# Shutdown, Restart and Logoff buttons not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, shutdown, panel, notification-area

I was working on Ubuntu 13.10 and everything was good until I entered `sudo shutdown -P -h now` to shutdown my computer.
After that when I switched on the power buttons under the setting icon on the top right corner won't work.

I have Cairo and the power options work for Cairo, but it is annoying that my system power buttons are not functional. Nothing happens on clicking them.

Comment: Please can anyone provide any help with this issue.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, try this:

Edit `/usr/lib/cairo-dock/cairo-dock-launcher-API-daemon as root` (if a blank/new document is created: cancel it and edit `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/cairo-dock/cairo-dock-launcher-API-daemon` as root)

Add the following at line 33 (After anything in that line):

```
from time import sleep
```

And add the following at line 241 (just right before ULWatcher()):

```
sleep(5)
```

Then restart the session or the computer.
Hope that helps, good luck and have fun.